# Unpack binary with variable length in PHP

Tags: php, binary, unpack

I have a problem unpacking a binary string containing fields with variable length.

The string contains several values and the first byte at the beginning of each variable value is describing the length of value. Basically, I know the datatype of each field, but not its length.

With an example I have something like:

```
$binary = "7Stefano5Italy38";
```

That has to be decoded with:

```
$value = unpack("A7NAME/A5NATION/sAGE", $binary);
```

That produces

```
$value = array(
    'NAME'   => 'Stefano',
    'NATION' => 'Italy',
    'AGE'    => 38
);
```

Is there a way to unpack using variable unpack syntax?

```
$value = unpack("A*NAME/A*NATION/sAGE", $binary);
```

... Forcing interpreter to understand that the first byte of a record is the record length or do I have to unpack it with different commands to the following?

1. Get 1st field length starting from byte 0
2. Get 1st field value
3. Get 2nd field length starting from byte 0 + 1st field length
4. Get 2nd field value
5. (...)

To show you a real example, this is the typical record structure that I have to unpack:

```
NTEST/CHEAD/CSITE/CFLAG/CPARM/fRESULT/CnTEXT/CnALARM/COPT
```

Where field TEXT and ALARM has a variable length.

The binary string to be unpacked is not containing NULL terminators (\x0) and then cannot be parsed as Perl does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Pack/unpack - can it handle variable length strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632773/php-pack-unpack-can-it-handle-variable-length-strings)

Comment: I already have a look at this post but it's referred to "packing and unpacking of variable (null terminated)". The example that I show are not null (\0) terminated.

Comment: Doesn't look like php provides something for that format. What is producing it? Does the format have a name? (it's not e.g. asn.1 but ....?)

Comment: The format is called STDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Test_Data_Format)
A typical record example is described to page 35 of file format spec (http://casey.marshall.googlepages.com/stdfv4-spec.pdf)

Comment: oh oh? "Decoding the STDF variable length binary field data format to extract ASCII text is non-trivial as it involves a detailed comprehension of the STDF specification" - how much afford are you willing to invest in this? The wikipedia page for example links to a c library. That plus [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) might give you a working php extension to handle the data.

Comment: I'm confident to have a complete comprehension of STDF and, by the way, I want to invest all my afford on it... but this is not the topic of discussion. I just want to know if there's a smart way to decode a binary string where certain field has length on 1st byte and value from 2nd. Then if feasible and fast enough, I'll deploy this approach to parse STDF.